# Returning xml content on a client API request in eXist-db

Tags: exist-db

In eXist 4.7, I have a simple API end point as an XQuery .xqm which  receives a short XML document from a client (ie. an HTML form in a browser). I currently only send back a response of 200 or 400. For example, in simplified form:

```
if (request:get-method()="POST")
    then
        let $eval := validate:my-api-doc(request:get-data())
        return 
                if ($eval/@status = "ok")
                then response:set-status-code(200)
                else response:set-status-code(400)

    else response:set-status-code(405)
```

I now want to start sending XML (or possibly other content) back to the client. For example, if the user is creating a document with a mandatory "title" field and they submit it empty, I want to send back to the client the response:

```
    <errors>
        <error element="title">Mandatory field.</error>
    </errors>
```

How do I get this XML content into the HTTP response? I cannot find a  relevant eXist HTTP `response` function in the documentation at https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/response .

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get XML content into your HTTP response, just return it inline as you would return XML content for any other query:

```
return
    (
        response:set-status-code(405),
        <error>Oops!</error>
    )
```